# OAuth 2.0 access token request failed with error "must use HTTP POST"

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, connected-apps, postman

OAuth 2.0 Auth token request failed with below error

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "must use HTTP POST"
}
```

What does this error mean?

I am using Postman. Have a connected app.
I have used Post method, Url has https. *Same request works for other Orgs.*
Did I missed any configuration/Permission check?

```
https://testOrg.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id={{CLIENT_ID}}&client_secret={{CLIENT_SECRET}}&username={{USER_ID}}&password={{PASSWORD}}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem is with domain name used in url. :|

Using the domain as in "Setup > My Domain" fixed the issue.

I have used   :  https://testOrg.lightning.force.com/    (Did not work)

Supposed to be:  https://testOrg.my.salesforce.com/      (Worked)

Thanks.

Comment: In my case, it was definitely the domain. I sent everything in the URL including the password WITHOUT the token. It works! Thank you @Sriram

Answer (score 3):

The request parameters (*grant_type*, *client_id* and so on) must be sent in the request *body* . The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm) mention this (note the phrase *example request body*) but they aren't very explicit about this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Below s what your `POST` request should look like.Please note the password might need the password+token concatenated:

Endpoint: `https://XXXXX.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`

```
Request Body:

client_id: lorem-ipsum-a
client_secret: lorem-ipsum-b
username: lorem-ipsum-c
password: lorem-ipsum-d //**NOTE YOU MIGHT NEED TO DO PASSWORD+TOKEN**
grant_type:password
```

Comment: Security Token did not help :(
Any other check ?